# How can I Interact with an ethereum smart contract via Java

Tags: web3j

I have successfully created smart contract on Ethereum rinkeby network and deployed as well. 
Now, I want to call the methods of deployed contract through Java not through JS.
I know, there is one API web3j- through which we can interact with smart contracts but unfortunately I am not being able to get the exact lines of code.

If anyone has implemented this, then please share the code.

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [this](http://www.javamagazine.mozaicreader.com/JanFeb2017/Default/36/0#&pageSet=36&page=0&contentItem=0) article. Web3j also has tools for generating the java classes required for interacting with a smart contract.

Comment: Can you summarise what the article says in your answer? Link-only answers are discouraged because the link could go dead/missing at any time.